# Flutter: How to change color of bottom navigation icon when drawer is closed?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, navigation-drawer, flutter-bottomnavigation

In my flutter app, I used a bottom navigation bar with 6 options. The sixth option is a menu hamburger icon, which I'm using to open a side drawer.

#### What I'm struggling to do is:

When the drawer opens or closes, I expect the colour of the hamburger icon to change.
As a result, when the user clicks on the icon, I am able to correctly update the icon colour and the drawer opens. **However, after the drawer closes, I am unable to change the colour of the icon.**

Comment: Please add your codes

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if the drawer is open then the color should be green else it should be red:

```
color: Scaffold.of(context).isDrawerOpen ? Colors.green : Colors.red
```